# Regular Expressions and GBP(£)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a regular expression for email subjects but am looking to allow the user to also add in a GBP sign (£) anywhere in the subject with very little joy.

My expression as it stands is:

```
var subjectText = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\'\£](\s)?)+$/);
```

Within the function I call for validating the content is the following IF statement:

```
if (!subjectText) {
    alertMessage = alertMessage + 'You must enter a valid Subject\n';
}
```

No matter what I enter in to the Subject text field (as long as it has a £ in it), upon submitting the form I get the 'You must enter a valid subject' message.

Can someone please help?

Comment: what do you want to exclude then?

Comment: `£` is a normal character in regex, you don't need to escape it.

Comment: The issue is that my check is coming back as false when a £ sign is in the subject string

Comment: @CPB07: What is input string that you're trying?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. `alert(/^([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\'\£](\s)?)+$/.test("£9.99"));` displays `true`.

Comment: Updated my OP with a little more detail

Comment: What's the code for `nameTest`?

Comment: Is `if (!subjectText)` your real code? You're not even looking at any text fields.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would validate your subject using your regex: *(I'm only validating subject here)*

```
var alertMessage = "All's good.";
var subjectText = "Send me some £ pounds.";

var subjectRegex = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\'\£](\s)?)+$/);

console.log(subjectRegex.test(subjectText)); // true   

if (!subjectRegex.test(subjectText)) {
 alertMessage = 'You must enter a valid Subject\n';
}

alert(alertMessage); // All's good.
```

You could however simplify your regex by removing unnecessary escapes inside the character class `[]`

```
/^([\w.'£-]\s?)+$/
```

where `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`; and `.`, `'`, `£` does not need to be escaped and same for `-` when present at the start or the end (i.e. not part of a range).

Answer (score 0):

use the following expression will help:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9£\.\-\'](\s)?)+$/
```

as described in the comments. `£` is a normal character for regex and does not require escaping.

Suggest to modify your `IF` condition as follows:

```
 var subjectRegEx = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9£\.\-\'](\s)?)+$/);
 if (!subjectText.match(subjectRegEx)) {
    alertMessage = alertMessage + 'You must enter a valid Subject\n';
 }
```

Supposing  `subjectText` contains the value entered in the subject field.